# Sorting lines with selection sort on mouseclick

Tags: java, swing, sorting, paint, repaint

I'm working on a selection sort testing program. It takes an array of random numbers, 20-100 and paints them, when you run the program, a frame is displayed with lines painted according to the random numbers, when you click on the panel the lines are ordered by the selection sort. Here is what it should look like before click and after click.

[image]

I've got it to where I can either have it print with all random, like the first image, or sorted, like the second image. But I can't figure the mouse click out. I thought I had it correct in my code here but I guess not.
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
/**
 *
 * @author matthewtingle
 */
public class AnimatedSelectionSortPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {
private static final int NUMBER_INDEXES = 50;
private static int[] number = new int[NUMBER_INDEXES];

/**
 * Creates new form AnimatedSelectionSortPanel
 */
public AnimatedSelectionSortPanel() {
    initComponents();
    loadArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_INDEXES; i++){
        if(i%10==0){
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("" + number[i]+", ");
        }else{
            System.out.print("" + number[i]+", ");
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    System.out.println("");

    drawPass(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_INDEXES; i++){
        if(i%10==0){
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print(""+ number[i]+ ", ");
        }else{
            System.out.print(""+ number[i]+ ", ");
        }
    }
}

private void loadArray() {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_INDEXES; i++) {
        number[i] = rnd.nextInt((100 - 20) + 1) + 20;
    }
}

public void drawPass(Graphics g) {
    int xBasePosition = 10;
    int yBasePosition = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_INDEXES; i++) {
        g.drawLine(xBasePosition,yBasePosition+20, xBasePosition, yBasePosition - number[i]);
        xBasePosition+=10;
    }
}
public void selectionSort(){
    for(int top = 0; top <= number.length - 2; top++){
        int minIndex = top;
        for (int i = top + 1; i <= number.length - 1; i++) {
            if (number[i] < number[minIndex]) {
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }swapElements(top,minIndex);
    }
}
private void swapElements(int index1, int index2){
    int tmp = number[index1];
    number[index1] = number[index2];
    number[index2] = tmp;
}


/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    jPanel1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jPanel1MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 500, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 150, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jPanel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
   selectionSort();
   repaint();
}                                    


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: Can you be more clear on what exactly isn't working about the code you implemented? For instance, when you click does nothing happen? Or incorrect results?

Comment: Right, nothing happens. When I run the program, the window shows up, with all of the lines random, which is what should happen. When I click, nothing happens when it should repaint in order according to the selection sort.

Comment: Do this step by step. Add System.out call into your mouseClicked() and check whether it's called. Then you will know the problem one of the 2  possible - 1) listener is not added/fired or 2) sort doesn't work. Then debug into the source one. You can post here SSCCE to let us check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to add this panel to a frame, but it did not even show up, unless I commented out the stuff from the "initComponents" method. I guess there's something wrong, but this auto-generated code is unreadable. I assume that the `jPanel1` (that the mouse listener is added to) is not placed properly. You could add the mouse listener to the animation panel directly. However, here is it as a SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
/**
 *
 * @author matthewtingle
 */
public class AnimatedSelectionSortPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    private static final int NUMBER_INDEXES = 50;
    private static int[] number = new int[NUMBER_INDEXES];

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
                f.getContentPane().add(new AnimatedSelectionSortPanel());
                f.setSize(600,300);
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Creates new form AnimatedSelectionSortPanel
     */
    public AnimatedSelectionSortPanel() {

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                selectionSort();
                repaint();
            }
        });

        loadArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_INDEXES; i++){
            if(i%10==0){
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.print("" + number[i]+", ");
            }else{
                System.out.print("" + number[i]+", ");
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        drawPass(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_INDEXES; i++){
            if(i%10==0){
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.print(""+ number[i]+ ", ");
            }else{
                System.out.print(""+ number[i]+ ", ");
            }
        }
    }

    private void loadArray() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_INDEXES; i++) {
            number[i] = rnd.nextInt((100 - 20) + 1) + 20;
        }
    }

    public void drawPass(Graphics g) {
        int xBasePosition = 10;
        int yBasePosition = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_INDEXES; i++) {
            g.drawLine(xBasePosition,yBasePosition+20, xBasePosition, yBasePosition - number[i]);
            xBasePosition+=10;
        }
    }
    public void selectionSort(){
        for(int top = 0; top <= number.length - 2; top++){
            int minIndex = top;
            for (int i = top + 1; i <= number.length - 1; i++) {
                if (number[i] < number[minIndex]) {
                    minIndex = i;
                }
            }swapElements(top,minIndex);
        }
    }
    private void swapElements(int index1, int index2){
        int tmp = number[index1];
        number[index1] = number[index2];
        number[index2] = tmp;
    }
}
```

BTW: If the intention is to really show this as an **animated** sorting process, you'll have to reconsider some of the existing structures. Precognitive warning: It will **NOT** be sufficient to add some `Thread.sleep` somewhere in your "swapElements" method or so. You'll have to discouple the sorting process and the painting process (that is, the sorting has to happen in an own thread), and you must be able to display *intermediate* states of the sorting process.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was a big help.